# Are 26" racing wheels still being produced?

Tags: wheels

It seems like all new road and triathlon bicycles are being made with 28" wheels and I've found it almost impossible to get 26" wheels for and older tri bike. Are they still being manufactured?

Comment: I suspect you mean 28" and 26" as a 28 foot bicycle wheel would be impressive, if a bit unwieldy when you actually came to ride it.

Comment: That's the bike they built for Spinal Tap.

Answer (score 6):

Quick answer is yes.

http://www.zipp.com/wheels/404-650c-tubular

http://www.corima.com/boutique/default.cfm?basketAction=add&reference=161102
 - if that link doesn't work it is for 650c Corima Wheels.

Answer (score 1):

you can ask you local shop to build one for you, they are not worse than wheelset ones if your mix of parts were right and the shop knows what they are doing.